# How to change the colour of certain PlotMarkers

Tags: plotting, legending

**Example data**

```
data =
 <|15 -> 10.374822`, 16 -> 10.34133`, 17 -> 10.309573`, 
  18 -> 10.291027`, 19 -> 10.276617`, 20 -> 10.295909`, 
  21 -> 10.352042`, 22 -> 10.352042`|>;
```

I want to highlight the three largest values in the following manner:

```
sort = ReverseSort[DeleteDuplicates @ ReverseSort @ data][[;; 3]];
```

<|15 -> 10.3748, 22 -> 10.352, 16 -> 10.3413|>

```
call = Thread[Keys[sort] -> Callout @@@ Transpose[{Values[sort], {"a", "b", "c"}}]]
```

{15 -> Callout[10.3748, "a"], 22 -> Callout[10.352, "b"],
16 -> Callout[10.3413, "c"]}

```
plot = <|data, call|>;

ListLinePlot[
 Values @ plot,
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.002],
 DataRange -> MinMax @ Keys[plot],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameTicks -> Keys[plot],
 GridLines -> Automatic,
 PlotMarkers -> {\[FilledSquare], 24}]
```

[image]

**Two questions**:

1. How can I change the colour of the `PlotMarkers` at positions `a`, `b` and `c` to `Red` ?
2. How can I change the size of `PlotMarkers` ? (the `24` in the above example doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question 1:
Combining ListLinePlot for all datapoints and ListPlot for a,b,c positions only.

```
Show[
  ListLinePlot[Values@plot, BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.002], 
   DataRange -> MinMax@Keys[plot], Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> Keys[plot], GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", 16}],
  ListPlot[Normal@sort /. Rule -> List, PlotMarkers -> 
    {Style["\[FilledSquare]", Red, 16]}]
  ]
(*Output*)
```

[image]

Question 2: Converting FilledSquare to String makes it resizable

```
Show[
  ListLinePlot[Values@plot, BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.002], 
   DataRange -> MinMax@Keys[plot], Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> Keys[plot], GridLines -> Automatic, 
   PlotMarkers -> {"\[FilledSquare]", 18}],
  ListPlot[Normal@sort /. Rule -> List, PlotMarkers -> 
        {Style["\[FilledSquare]", Red, 22]}]
]
(*Output*)
```

[image]